# How to hide header in SugarCRM community edition

Tags: php, zend-framework, sugarcrm

Actually i am new to sugarcrm and zend frame work too .if anything not able to understand my following question means comment here . Now I am go for my query   actually I need to hide the my header portion in all the page .
So I followed this link

http://sugarcrm-customization-ash.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-hide-all-tab-from-menu-bar.html

mine version is : **sugarcrm community Version 6.5.23**

[image]

**STEP 1 :**

Go to file

```
 /include/MVC/View/SugarView.php
```

open the file in the php editor

**STEP 2 :**

Go to line number 509 and comment the line

```
$groupTabs[$app_strings['LBL_TABGROUP_ALL']]['modules'] = $fullModuleList;
below that add a new code
$groupTabs[$app_strings['LBL_TABGROUP_ALL']]['modules'] = '';
```

So when you set that All menu tab only display one item under the subtab.

**STEP 3 :**

Now moving forward got to line number 513 and comment the line

```
$allGroup = $app_strings['LBL_TABGROUP_ALL'];
```

below that add a new code

```
$allGroup = $app_strings['LBL_TABGROUP_ALL']  = '';
```

For the higher version means Sugarcrm 6.5.* use the following way

```
/include/MVC/View/SugarView.php

Find for the " $ss->assign("groupTabs",$groupTabs);"

just above this line put this code

//this code is used to hide the all tab

unset($groupTabs['All']);
$ss->assign("groupTabs",$groupTabs);
```

Its work charm but its hide the header part in list view and some pages only when I go detail view or edit view its showing all header again not hiding header part in detail view . so I want the hide the header part in each and every page . I don’t have much knowledge about sugarcrm and zend too so . what can do where can I do .
Sorry for my bad English

thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Goes You are: follow the steps.

**1. Copy theme folder from :

root/themes 
 
 to 

/custom/themes**

**2. Open `style.css` 
    Search and Add this code**

```
 #header
    {
       min-width: 85em;
       display: none;
     }
```

Now your header will hide I sure , Because it working on my PC.

You hide the tabs Without going in to the code.

just go to 
**1. Go to Admin Panel. 

2. Go to Configure Module Menu Filters

3. Just Delete All The Tabs.**

But this will Not hide the Tab "ALL"
Because without menu or tab you can't navigate , Without navigation it hard to work on any website.

Comment: i need to hide all  marked red area .basically the header and menu bar

Comment: That's i need . i already have another way for navigate the pages . right now i need to hide header part all

Comment: please check i edit my answer if is help full upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: thank you so much @Amitesh kumar . its working perfect. i did accepted and upvoted .

Comment: I did by myself then i posted the answer i am also learning it.

Comment: i'm completely new to sugarcrm and zendframe work . once again thank you so much for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124366/discussion-between-amitesh-kumar-and-jyothi).